# IOS Universal Linking not working, still opens website

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to add Universal Linking to app that I am working on.  I have all of the proper settings and URLs set up on the dev account. I am using React Native and React native Router flux. The router is set up to be domainname.me/flow/:flow_id.

For the apple JSON file should I have the wild card "*" in paths or should I have the '/flow'

I have to domains under the Associated Domains

```
applinks:appname.me (domain is .me not .com)
applinks:www.appname.me
```

I have the apple-app-site-associatifile below.

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "<teamID>.me.appname.ios",
        "paths": [
          "/flow/"          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you but it's worth a try, do also add the scheme as in the http:// part in the applinks in xcode.

Comment: so under the domains in Associated domains it would be applinks:https://domainanme.me?

Comment: Tried that and it didnt make a difference. Its still loading the web page and not even asking to open up the app

Comment: Have you made sure that the file which is hosted is accessible and that the name of the file is correct?

Comment: Everything is correct on that end, I have seen people have issues launching them on the emulators. Is a physical device better or is there a way for them to work on the emualators?

Comment: I don’t think emulator/simulator is the issue here. Normally when the universal links are set up correctly and the app is installed on a phone, Apple adds a banner on the top of the web page saying “Open in app”.

Answer (score 3):

It was an emulator problem. For some reason Universal Links wouldn't open there, but do on a physical device.